# UITableView Reuse issues

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MonthViewPopUpCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjcet = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MonthViewPopUpCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibObjcet objectAtIndex:0];

        cellTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontB size:size4];
        cellSubtitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontR size:size4];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cellTitle.text = @"11:03";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

For some reason i don't understand, the tableview reuses my custom cell wrongly. I thought this code would make the first cell show 11:03 and all the rest would show me 10:00 (as in the xib file), but some other cells show 11:03 as well, and their position is changing when i scroll up and down like crazy...

Can someone show me what i've done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Simply add an else part for if condition with cellTitle.text = @"10.00";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't reuse the same cell in the same position, it just takes a cell that is already stored in memory and reuse it for the table in another position, so you need to set the text of it every time, for example:

```
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjcet = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MonthViewPopUpCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibObjcet objectAtIndex:0];

        cellTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontB size:size4];
        cellSubtitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontR size:size4];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cellTitle.text = @"11:03";
    }
    else{
        cellTitle.text = @"10:00";
    }
```

Comment: But where do you init cell?

Comment: i tried it but it says "user of undeclared identifier 'cell'"

Comment: Well... If i add this line: UITableViewCell *cell;

I put it above the first line of you code and it works...

Comment: And i'm sorry i'm not accepting, but it doesn't let me cause i have less than 15 points of rep

Answer (score 0):

Usually cell gets reused once it moves out of the visible area of the UITableView. You can do one thing. Also check in nib whether your custom cell's reusable identifier is set to 
MonthViewPopUpCell

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MonthViewPopUpCell"; ////As you have specified in XIB

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjcet = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MonthViewPopUpCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibObjcet objectAtIndex:0];

        cellTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontB size:size4];
        cellSubtitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontR size:size4];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cellTitle.text = @"11:03";
    }else {
        cellTitle.text = @"10:00";
   }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to make a method -(void)prepareForReuseCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell;

Comment: did you check the xib and set the reusable identifier for the custom cell as like you use in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the good way to call custom cell. I hope it will work.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

MonthViewPopUpCell *cell = (MonthViewPopUpCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nibObjcet = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MonthViewPopUpCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nibObjcet objectAtIndex:0];

    cellTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontB size:size4];
    cellSubtitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontR size:size4];
}

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cellTitle.text = @"11:03";
}else{

    cellTitle.text = @"10:00";

}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm only using an extra xib file for the custom cell. Not using a class for this

Comment: In your case the cell is in a weak position. Try like this                        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; or create separate UITableViewCell class.